# Is it possible to create a web service that changes websites CSS?

Tags: html, css, web-services

Specifically, I'm thinking about a service that hides the price in online shops so that I can share the link without the price with someone.

Comment: You'd either need to control the server and modify what it shows, or control the user's browser and modify what it displays.  Which approach are you taking?

Comment: I mean a general solution for many websites, without having any access to the server. So I guess this leaves me with second option. Does it mean it's only doable via a browser extension or is it possible without the link receiver having to install anything?

Comment: You could perhaps proxy the request through a server that you control.  So you'd send a user to a link to your server with whatever parameters that link needs.  Your server would fetch the data from the 3rd party site (ideally via an API call, but failing that you could scrape the data from their web page) and then display whatever you want to the user.  Obvious drawbacks here involve authentication/authorization if you're trying to fetch data on behalf of someone else.  How to handle that can easily differ between different 3rd party systems.